# Parallel.ForEach causing SQL query to not work

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm paging through a set of data (example of query below) to verify some information. When I use Parallel.ForEach, the SQL command to get the second page of results comes back empty. If I break on the return statement and move the active line back to the Repository, it will return the results I'm looking for. Changing the Parallel.ForEach to a standard C# foreach works as expected.

Example of the query:

```
SELECT TOP 500
        StudentID,
        StudentName
    FROM Student
    WHERE StudentVerified IS NULL
```

Example of the code...

```
while(true)
{
    using(var rep = new Repository())
    {
        var students = rep.GetStudents();
        if (students.Length == 0) return false;
        Parallel.ForEach(students, (student) =>
        {
            rep.StudentVerified(student.StudentID, true);
        });
    }
}
```

Any help to figure out why the second page of results is coming back empty is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: likely `Repository.StudentVerified` is not thread safe. You need to show the code for it.

Comment: It's a simple SQL UPDATE statement. However, it shouldn't matter if it was thread safe or not, the SELECT command should still either return data or there should be exceptions. Returning no results is definitely not expected.

Comment: _"Changing the Parallel.ForEach to a standard C# foreach works as expected"_ - as a follow up to Scott, setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to `1` in options (just for the sake of it) will likely result in it working too.  Thus the problem isn't so much _"Parallel.ForEach causing SQL query to not work"_ rather that your code is potentially not thread-safe.  If `Repository.StudentVerified` are all sharing the same db connection, that is perhaps your problem right there.  Same applies to EF

Comment: It is using the same connection, but why would that cause the SELECT to return 0 results? The SELECT is not in the ForEach, so it shouldn't be effected by any issues with unsafe code. As a note, it is straight SqlCommands in the Repository and Repository.StudentVerified is working as expected, no errors and the values are getting set as expected.

Comment: "it shouldn't matter if it was thread safe or not" is very very very wrong.... You still have 1 SqlConnection and that is not thread safe...

Comment: Seems like there is something there, I changed MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 1 and it did work as expected. However, I still don't understand why it would fail silently. Why wasn't there an exception? Why did it effect the GetStudents which is outside the Parallel.ForEach, but not effect the StudentVerified which is in the Parallel.ForEach? I've run this across tens of thousands of records with no exceptions or errors (other than GetStudents returning 0 results).

Comment: FYI, I've updated the code to show that the Repository is actually recreated each loop (which establishes a new connection). Obviously this doesn't help, but I'm trying to figure out why it failed the way it did, so I wanted to make sure the code reflected the actual code a little better.

Comment: The repository is not re-created "each loop", it would need to be re-created inside the parallel block to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you comments you appear to be sharing a `SqlConnection` between requests. That class is not thread safe. [`SqlConnection` is optimised to have many short lived connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx), create the connection as you need it then dispose of it when you are done by using a `using` block.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem better. Do you have any idea why it is silently failing? Or why the code outside of the Parallel.ForEach is failing but not the code inside of it? The behavior seems to be completely counter-intuitive to me.